# jQuery plugin options when loaded via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, getscript

When loading a plugin via ajax I am unable to pass options to it. However, if I pass the options to the plugin when the plugin is included normally (along with the rest of the page rather than ajax) it works fine.

```
// Get the script
$.getScript('/js/gallery.min.js')
 .done(function() {

     // Initiate scroll plugin on load
     $('.section-gallery').smoothDivScroll({
         manualContinuousScrolling: true,
         autoScrollingMode: 'onStart'
     });
});
```

The plugin itself is working, but only gets the default value, not with the options I wish to pass with it.

The script I am loading uses the plugin [Smooth Div Scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/)

Update: 
There is a link to a codepen of it here: http://cdpn.io/Hopgm However, it actually seems to work there :/ so maybe it's a localhost thing. Oddly, another plugin I'm loading seems to work, and this one works occasionally. I have tried adding a timeout, but that didn't work. @Dean.DePue - I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Can you provide a dummy link or something. It would be nice to work on console.

Comment: Yes, plz, a little more code and HTML

Comment: Can you pass values in the function call, e.g.   
    function(value1, value2, value3) {
etc..

Comment: Wont' let me comment for some reason. See above edit